# Best C++ practice for retrieving variables from config files

Tags: c++, c++17, config

The use case is quite common: I have a few variables that should be accessible globally (by various classes) and initialized from a configuration file. I can't decide the best way to do this.

1. Options struct is owned by someone and passed around:

```
struct Opts {
        int op1;
        double op2;
};

int main() {
        Opts o = {3, 0.5};
        // Pass this around as const reference, or potentially copying
        return 0;
}
```

2. Use static vars for some Options struct.

```
struct Opts {
        inline static int op1;
        inline static double op2;
};

int main() {
        Opts::op1 = 3;
        Opts::op2 = 0.5;
        // No passing around, but use Opts::op1 instead
        return 0;
}
```

3. Use static vars, but sorta differently (not really).

```
struct Opts {
        static int op1;
        static double op2;
};
int Opts::op1;
double Opts::op2;

int main() {
        Opts::op1 = 3;
        Opts::op2 = 0.5;
        // No passing around, but use Opts::op1 instead
        return 0;
}
```

What should I actually do here? I thought the best case would be static const vars to make sure no one changes these, but the values can only be obtained from some file (so seems like it has to be run time instead of compile time), even though they won't change at after initializing.

I *could* make it const refs if I don't make it static, but that just forces me to pass this around among many classes. I also wanted the class that *owns* these options to be different from the class that *parses* them. This would just be even uglier with either moving unique_ptr or copying.

Is there a way to get best of both worlds:

1. not having to pass things around excessively (hence the semantics of "static")
2. making sure that these can't be modified after initialization, at least indicating that is the case (hence the semantics of "const")?

Comment: `const` objects get initialized at runtime all the time.

Comment: I'm talking about both const and static. How do you initialize that at runtime? @SamVarshavchik

Comment: Write a healper function that reads the file and returns a non const object of the type you want.  Then all you do is `const static my_type my_variable = my_helper_function();`

Comment: That would require my_helper_function to be constexpr, if I'm not mistaken. The problem is we don't know if my_helper_function really is that simple. (Like, this helper function may not have a result that be figured out compile time?) @NathanOliver

Comment: It does not.  `constexpr static my_type my_variable = my_helper_function();` would, but what I suggested does not.  `const` in C++ doesn't really mean embed this value into the program.  While that can happen as an optimization, its real use is to make sure you don't try to modify a variable you shouldn't and having the compiler tell you when you do.

Comment: You are mistaken. This does not require a `constexpr` function.

Comment: compile gives `test14.C:7:31: error: call to non-‘constexpr’ function ‘const int getOp1()’
    7 |  const static int op1 = getOp1();`. How would this be called then?

Comment: Sorry.. would you be able to provide an example where this works?

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/h1jxhYdMo As you can see I initialize a `const Config` with the result of a non-`constexpr` function. I also initialize a `const static` member variable of `Config` using the same.

Comment: I see. Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

I commonly use a singleton Class.  A `config` object is instantiated at startup time, and it reads the content of the file.  It contains "getters" which return the values to you, and it might also contain "setters" which allow those values to be changed – in which case it also rewrites the underlying file. The settings file is simply how this object "persists" itself from one run to the next.

The object is also responsible for checking the contents of the settings to ensure that they are proper.  If someone edits the file incorrectly, the object is going to throw a meaningful exception.  So, if it *doesn't* do that, you know the settings file is good.  The "setters" are equally suspicious: if some other part of the program tries to store an incorrect value, the object will catch the attempt and throw an exception.